# Get the index name AND column name for each cell in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe populated with True/False values.  I want to iterate through each cell of the dataframe and if the value is True, **return the index name and column name at that cell location** (or else, their row and column index).

- I thought there might be a quick pandas way using `dataframe.applymap` with a function that returns the col,row of the cell, but I don't know how to call the index and column name for a particular cell.  Basically its like looking for `.iloc[]` in reverse.
- or else I'd be happy with getting a dataframe back that is a separate dataframe that is all the true values.

Comment: `np.where(df)` or `np.nonzero(df)`?

Comment: *getting a dataframe back that is a separate dataframe that is all the true values* - with what shape?

Comment: `[*df.stack()[df.stack()].index]`

Comment: When you say *"get a dataframe"*, the best answer depends on whether you want to do further individual processing on each cell which is True and its row index, col name (use`.melt()`), or preserve the original shape. There is also `.to_dict(...)`, but that's not what you want here.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you could try melting ([pd.melt](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html)) your dataframe while keeping the index as your variable :

```py
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice([True, False], (5, 5)), columns=list("abcde"), index=list("fghij")
)
#   a   b   c   d   e
# f False   True    True    True    False
# g True    True    False   False   True
# h False   True    True    False   False
# i True    True    False   False   False
# j True    True    False   True    True


df.reset_index().melt(id_vars='index').query('value == True')
```

outputs :

```py
  index variable value
1   g   a   True
3   i   a   True
4   j   a   True
5   f   b   True
6   g   b   True
7   h   b   True
8   i   b   True
9   j   b   True
10  f   c   True
12  h   c   True
15  f   d   True
19  j   d   True
21  g   e   True
24  j   e   True
```